# Setting file attributes in Swift

Tags: swift, macos

How would I set the file attributes (such as NSCreationDate) for a file in Swift for OSX?

I can do this in Objective-C but can't figure out how to do it in Swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically the same in Swift. This sets the creation time to the current time:

```
let path = "/path/to/file"
let attributes = [
    NSFileCreationDate: NSDate()
]

do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().setAttributes(attributes, ofItemAtPath: path)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Make sure you DON'T do this in playground. Playground only has permission to write to its local folder. Put this into a Swift project:

Answer (score 5):

for swift 3 use:

```
//let path = "/path/to/file"

let attributes = [
    FileAttributeKey.creationDate: NSDate(),
    // FileAttributeKey.modificationDate: NSDate() for modification date...
]

do {
    try FileManager.default.setAttributes(attributes, ofItemAtPath: path)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```